# Xamarin Forms "Attempting to JIT compile method" "_Decimal_object_object_Nullable`1<int>" Error With EntityFramework SQL Lite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Having an issue running my xamarin forms app on the iOS device. It runs fine in the simulator. The app is using EntityFramework to persist data down to the device. If the class that I'm persisting has a nullable object in it then it throws the following error:

> "System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper runtime-invoke) :runtime_invoke_void__this___Decimal_object_object_Nullable`1<int>_Nullable`1_object_Nullable`1<int>_DateTime_object_object_object_Nullable`1_Nullable`1<DateTime>_Nullable`1_object_object_object_object_object_int_object_object_Nullable`1<int> (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ for more information.\n\n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)\n  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Linq.Expressions.Interp
>   reter.ExceptionHelpers.UnwrapAndRethrow (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/Interpreter/Utilities.cs:172 \n  at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.NewInstruction.Run (System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00026] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/Interpreter/NewInstruction.cs:39 \n  at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00015] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/Interpreter/Interpreter.cs:63 \n  at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet] (T0 arg0) [0x0001c] in <41fdc0bc3c7345a
>   ebac34baf698c1a1e>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry+OriginalValues..ctor (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry entry) [0x00011] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.EnsureOriginalValues () [0x0000d] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntrySubscriber.SnapshotAndSubscribe (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry entry) [0x0000f] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry entry) [0x00094] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState oldState, Mi
>   crosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState newState, System.Boolean acceptChanges) [0x00160] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState entityState, System.Boolean acceptChanges, System.Nullable`1[T] forceStateWhenUnknownKey) [0x00034] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntryGraphNode node, System.Boolean force) [0x0003f] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at (wrapper unknown) System.Object.gsharedvt_out()\n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] handleNode) [0x00000] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at (wrapper unknown) System.Object
>   .gsharedvt_in()\n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState entityState, System.Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey) [0x0001b] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry entry, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState entityState) [0x00013] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityStates (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] entities, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState entityState) [0x00024] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.AddRange (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] entities) [0x00012] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.Intern
>   alDbSet`1[TEntity].AddRange (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] entities) [0x00000] in <6819f4d14a5b46d281e2f19f98f40ca8>:0 \n  at myapp.Mobile.Data.Persistence.Repositories.Repository`1[TEntity].AddRange (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] entities) [0x0000c] in <19fa30c8b89e4df98a2ac6fb45ffc5ca>:0 \n  at myapp.Mobile.Services.FatController+<PerformAction>d__0`1[T].MoveNext () [0x001fd] in <9465b9d8d8894975b6d390e6d0a1bc80>:0 "

This seems to be due to the properties in the class that it's trying to persist to storage that are nullable like:

```
public class MyTable
{
    #region Instance Properties
    [Key]
    public int MyID { get; set; }        
    public int? MyNullableID { get; set; }
    #endregion Instance Properties
```

}

Any ideas why this is only an issue on the device and not on the simulator or on any other platforms (UWP, Android work fine)?

Comment: 1) Apple excludes the execution of dynamic code on device due to their security requirements, the simulator is just that, a "simulator", that is running in context of macOS and thus the dynamic code is available for execution. 2) Google/Android does not restrict dynamic code execution. 3) EntityFramework works by performing reflection/Linq tree generation and the dynamic code that is generated is executed via an interpreter and thus does not ever get JIT'd to native instructions (the reason it has a performance impact on limited resource mobile devices.

Comment: 4) UWP execution via the native AOT compiler works because of that IL interpreter being used at runtime for those Linq expression trees.

Comment: I would create the simplest test case you can and submit it as an issue on the EntityFramework GitHub repo. Note: There are other open and closed issues related to "AOT" issues but this might be an edge case that is not currently covered (and possible an edge case not cover by Mono)